# <? extends Class> and <? super Class> in Java - why it works this way?

Tags: java, generics

Yet another novice, trying to comprehend Java Generics.
I've observed all topics, I found, but I still have huge questions.
Could you please explain me the following things:

1. `<? extends SomeClass>` means, that `?` is "any type", and `extends SomeClass` means, that this any type can be only a subclass of `SomeClass`.
   OK, I write two elementary classes:

```java
abstract class Person {
    private String name;
    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class Student extends Person {
    public Student(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
}
```

Class `Student` will be `?` in our example. `? extends Person`, to be precise.
Then I'm trying to add new student to ArrayList, that, as I understand from written above, applies all classes, that are subclasses of Person:

```java
Student clarissa = new Student("Clarissa Starling");
List<? extends Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(clarissa); //Does not compile
```

Eclipse says:

> "The method add(capture#3-of ? extends Person) in the type
>   List is not applicable for the
>   arguments (Student)"

How can class `Student` be not applicable, when we declared List, paramethrized by `<? extends Person>`, and `Student` exactly extends class `Person`?

Nevertheless, the following code:

```java
List<? super Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(clarissa);
```

compiles and works well (`list.get(0)`, passed to println method, shows me the correct result of `toString` invocation).
As I understand, `List<? super Person>` means, that I can pass to this list any type, that is super type for our `Person` class (in our case it is `Object` class only). But we see, that, contrary to logic, we can easy add subclass Student to our `List<? super Person>`!

OK, put aside our emotions, and let's see, what can happen with Clarissa Starling in our collection. Let's take our class `Student`, and add a couple of methods to it:

```java
class Student extends Person {
    private int grant;
    public Student(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public void setGrant(int grant) {
        this.grant = grant;
    }

    public int getGrant() {
        return this.grant;
    }

}
```

Then we pass an object, instantiated from this renewed class (our object "clarissa", for example), to `List<? extends Person>`. Doing this, we mean, that we can store subclass in the collection of its superclasses. Maybe, I don't understand some fundamenthal ideas, but at this stage I don't see any difference between adding subclass to the collection of its superclasses and the assigning of the reference to object "clarissa" to variable, typed Person. We have the same reducing of invokable methods, when we want to treat one of them, using our superclass variable. So, why `List<? extends SomeClass>` does not work the same way, wherein `List<? super SomeClass>` works conversely?

2. I don't understand the fundamenthal difference between `<T>` (or `<E>`, or any other letter from appropriate part of JLS) and `<?>`. Both `<T>` and `<?>` are *typeholders*, so why we have two "keywords" (this symbols are NOT keywords, I just used this word for emphasizing the heavy meaning of both symbols in Java language) for the same purpose?

Comment: Suppose you have two classes `Student` & `Teacher` which extends `Person`. Now, you made a list `List<? extends Person>` and suppose you added `Student` in it then how would you become sure that `list.get(0)` will return you only `Student` and not `Teacher`? To prevent this ambiguity it is not allowed.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs

Comment: I expect, that list.get(0) will return an object, that will be casted to superclass type, and I'll be able to invoke only methods, declared in superclass (Person).

Comment: @user2004685 there's no ambiguity, one would expect the List to return an object that's either a Student or a Teacher. Other typed languages allow for this, it's a Java generics limitation.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The way I look at it is this - the placeholder `T` stands in for a definite type and in places where we need to know the actual type we need to be able to work it out. In contrast the wildcard `?` means any type and I will never need to know what that type is. You can use the `extends` and `super` bounds to limit that wildcard in some way but there's no way to get the actual type.

So, if I have a `List<? extends MySuper>` then all I know about it is that every object in it implements the `MySuper` interface, and all the objects in that list are of the same type. I don't know what that type is, only that it's some subtype of `MySuper`. That means I can get objects out of that list so long as I only need to use the `MySuper` interface. What I can't do is to put objects into the list because I don't know what the type is - the compiler won't allow it because even if I happen to have an object of the right type, it can't be sure at compile time. So, the collection is, in a sense a read-only collection.

The logic works the other way when you have `List<? super MySuper>`. Here we're saying the collection is of a definite type which is a supertype of `MySuper`. This means that you can always add a `MySuper` object to it. What you can't do, because you don't know the actual type, is retrieve objects from it. So you've now got a kind of write-only collection.

Where you use a bounded wildcard versus the 'standard' generic type parameter is where the value of the differences start to become apparent. Let's say I have 3 classes `Person`, `Student` and `Teacher`, with `Person` being the base that `Student` and `Teacher` extend. In an API you may write a method that takes a collection of `Person` and does something to every item in the collection. That's fine, but you really only care that the collection is of some type that is compatible with the `Person` interface - it should work with `List<Student>` and `List<Teacher>` equally well. If you define the method like this

```
public void myMethod(List<Person> people) {
    for (Person p: people) {
        p.doThing();
    }
}
```

then it can't take `List<Student>` or `List<Teacher>`. So, instead, you would define it to take `List<? extends Person>`...

```
public void myMethod(List<? extends Person> people){
    for (Person p: people) {
        p.doThing();
    }
}
```

You can do that because `myMethod` never needs to add to the list. And now you find that `List<Student>` and `List<Teacher>` can both be passed into the method.

Now, let's say that you've got another method which wants to add Students to a list. If the method parameter takes a `List<Student>` then it can't take a `List<People>` even though that should be fine. So, you implement it as taking a `List<? super Student>`
e.g.

```
public void listPopulatingMethod(List<? extends Student> source, List<? super Student> sink) {
    for (Student s: source) {
        sink.add(s);
    }
}
```

This is the heart of PECS, which you can read about in much greater detail elsewhere...
[What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/04/java-generics-quick-tutorial.html

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is excellent! Now I feel myself much more closer to understanding generics in Java. Additionally, I missed the fact, that, unlike `Person` and `Student` classes, there is no inheritance relations between `Person` and `Student` in `List<Person>` and `List<Student>` (as I understand, it's actually no relation between parameter types in this Lists because of type erasure?).

Comment: Yeah, so type-erasure means that 'under-the-hood' they're all just List's at run-time. To maintain type-safety the compiler needs to match up all the generic type parameters and make sure that everything's compatible. So inheritance relationships in generic type parameters end up working slightly differently than for things which can be verified by purely run-time type checking.

Comment: I still don't understand why you can't add, for example, a `new Dog()` to a `List<? extends Animal>`. Can't the compiler see that the dog class extends  animal?

Comment: Because the list could be List<Cat>, which is also a valid List<? extends Animal>. You can't add a Dog to a List<Cat> so the compiler can't *know* if its safe to add a Dog to a List<? extends Animal>.

Comment: @sisyphus So, How and what we can add in List<? extends Animal>

Comment: @San You can't add anything to a `List<? extends Animal>` because you don't know what the actual underlying type of the objects in the list are - so you can't convince the compiler that your method call is typesafe. You *can* take items from that list so long as you assign them to references of type `Animal`.

Comment: Ok, I understand `List<? extends Animal>`,  but, why we can add elements (for example Dog) when we use `List<? super Animal>` where super class of Animal is Object?...  I think we could add Dog or Cat indistinctly.

Comment: @Santosh i guess this is quite confusing. I try to get this the following way: In Java the list has a base type, and that type is a concrete type. When you say List<? extends Animal> you are NOT stating that the list containst elements whose base type is Animal as it that were the case then you could add a Cat or a Dog to it; the thing that you are stating is that the list will have a base type that extends Animal. So at runtime you have could List<Cat> or List<Rabbit> and those list are complaint with List<? extends Animal>. It is very very subtle the different and is not straightforward

Comment: @sisyphus sorry for annoying you... but ¿could you validate what I'm saying above?

Comment: @VictorZhdanov to solve you original problem if you need a list whose base type is Animal, and you want to add animals of any time you just use `List<Animal>`. See the working example. https://onecompiler.com/java/3xyqmagfu

Answer (score 5):

```
List<? super Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(clarissa); // clarissa is an instance of Student class
```

The reason why you can do things above, Suppose there is a Person class, Student class extends Person. You can think List means that in this List all elements is of class Person or superclass of Person, so when you add Person class instance or subclass of Person class, the implicit casting will happen.
e.g. Person person = new Student();

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<? super Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
        people.add(new Person());
        people.add(new Object()); // this will not compile
}
```

But if you add Object class instance into the list, explicit casting or down casting is required and the compiler does not know whether say (Person) Object can be successful.