# classA extends classB, how to have objects from classB in classA

Tags: java

I have this class:

```
public class Gradient extends Item<GradientRep> {

    /**
     * Initializes a new Gradient
     * @param x X-coordinate of the Item
     * @param y Y-coordinate of the Item
     * @param value The value of the gradient
     */

    public Gradient(int x, int y, int value, String type) {
        super(x, y);
        this.value = value;
        this.type = type;
    }

     ....
```

And I would like this class to "own" some objects of class *Item*, for example, I would like to retrieve from class *Gradient* this object:

```
Item MyItem = new Item()
```

Is there an obvious way to do this?

To give some background, for now the class Gradient only represent a fixed point on a map, which is not what we want for a Gradient. So, I want to propagate this gradient, and therefore when I instantiate a Gradient, I want it to provide other *Items* (with different coordinates on the map, which is dealt by the class Item).

Comment: Did you try to add a variable of type Item to Gradient? I don’t really see what the problem is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [<? extends Class> and <? super Class> in Java - why it works this way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35669112/extends-class-and-super-class-in-java-why-it-works-this-way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're after - but you could instanciate items from **Gradient** like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Gradient extends Item<GradientRep> {

    private final int value;
    private final String type;
    
    private ArrayList<Item<GradientRep>> items = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Initializes a new Gradient
     *
     * @param x     X-coordinate of the Item
     * @param y     Y-coordinate of the Item
     * @param value The value of the gradient
     */
    public Gradient(int x, int y, int value, String type) {
        super(x, y);
        this.value = value;
        this.type = type;
    }

    Item<GradientRep> getItem() {
        return new Item<>(x, y);
    }
}
```

The **Gradient** object will be an item, stores items in the `items` ArrayList (or your choice of ADT), and can generate new `Item` objects with the `getItem` method.

Comment: Thank you, actually I don't need the Items to be of "type" GradientRep, Can I just do Item getItem() { ... etc. ?

Comment: Sorry, I did not specified that the Item class is Abstract, and I would like to create Items objects in Gradient class, based on the values of x and y (for instance create an Item(x+1, y+2), and be able to access it once the Gradient class is instanciated)

Comment: If the `Item` class is abstract, you can't instanciate `Item` objects. If you would like objects 'like' items, you will need to either make `Item` not abstract, or create another child of `Item`. Maybe something like:

`public class Coordinate extends Item <> {`

Comment: And yes, you can have a raw use of `Item`, although I would avoid it if you could.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through this way as well:

```
public class Gradient extends Item<GradientRep> {
        Item myItem;
        /**
         * Initializes a new Gradient
         * @param x X-coordinate of the Item
         * @param y Y-coordinate of the Item
         * @param value The value of the gradient
         */
    
        public Gradient(int x, int y, int value, String type) {
            super(x, y);
            this.value = value;
            this.type = type;
            myItem = new Item();
        }
```

you can access the field as **gradient.myItem**

If you are making the field static, then use **Gradient.myItem**